# How to solve Error 400 : redirect_uri_mismatch when uploading a video on youtube via a python script?

Tags: python, api, google-cloud-platform, redirect, uri

I am using a python script https://github.com/zackmawaldi/YouTube-shorts-generator
to generate and upload automatically youtube videos. But when the step of the uploading comes, my browser gets opened by the script, and I get an error, it seems to be linked with my google project's settings, authorized URI's and stuff[My google project console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aeASy.png)

[The google page that opens and the error I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TmEcS.png)

I am very noob in programming but I will do my very best to understand your answers, I am able to learn fast, just please use understandable vocabulary for a noob and I should be able to apply your answers easily.
Thank you so much in advance

I tried adding multiple URI's in my google project's settings such as http://localhost:8080, https://localhost:8080, https://youtube.com and was expecting for google to redirect me to these URLs as soon as I opened the google page that uploads the video, but I get an error instead

[Here is the code file that opens up my browser and brings me the google error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElIX7.png)

Console returns:

```html
Your browser has been opened to visit:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX-uipoum0d75tgk7hkblg293lvurer5h4n.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8080%2F&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com&access_type=offline&response_type=code
```

Comment: You have a redirect URL mismatch but you do not show the URL that you are using. That setting does not redirect you, it validates that the redirect_url in the request matches.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The `redirect_uri` appears correct. Double-check the `client_id` value.